# Flash/ActionScript3 crashes on getPixel/32

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Question: The below code crashes flash...
Why?

The crash causing lines seem to be

//var uiColor:uint = bmpd.getPixel(i,j);

            var uiColor:uint = bmpd.getPixel32(i,j);

            trace("Color: "+ uiColor);


I am trying to take a snapshot of a movieclip and iterate through all pixels in the image and get the pixel's color.

```
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.geom.*;


function takeSnapshot(mc:MovieClip):BitmapData 
{
var sp:BitmapData = new BitmapData(mc.width, mc.height, true, 0x000000);
sp.draw(mc, new Matrix(), new ColorTransform(), "normal");
return sp;
}

var mcMyClip:MovieClip=new MovieClip()
var xxx:cMovieClipLoader=new cMovieClipLoader(); 

xxx.LoadImageAbsSize(mcMyClip,"http://localhost/flash/images/picture.gif", 500,500)

//this.addChild(mcMyClip);

function WhenImageIsLoaded()
{
var bmpd:BitmapData=takeSnapshot(mcMyClip);

var i,j:uint;

for(i=0; i < bmpd.width;++i)
{
    for(j=0; j < bmpd.height;++j)
    {
        //var uiColor:uint = bmpd.getPixel(i,j);
        var uiColor:uint = bmpd.getPixel32(i,j);
        trace("Color: "+ uiColor);
    }
}


var myBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmpd);



this.addChild(myBitmap);
}

setTimeout(WhenImageIsLoaded,1000);
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean when you say "crashes flash"?

Comment: Just ran the code in an fla and it all worked fine for me. I ran in CS4 on a mac. Would seem it's more of a flash-ide/environment problem than a code problem.

Comment: Yea, you mean a Vista x64 problem. I've given up filing bug reports, I still need to do other things ;-))

Comment: Can you post the stack trace? Can you publish it with debugging enabled? That will tell you exactly which line the error occurs on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

There were 3 problems at once:
1. It has transparency, so only GetPixel32 works
2. mcMyClip.width & height returns a wrong value mcMyClip.getBounds(mcMyClip).width & height returns the correct value (because the original movieclip is a resized one)
3. 800x600 picture = 480'000 points * 1 trace messages in the blink of a second, which is the cause for the crash (might actually be a Vista problem...)

Comment: For #0, 0x000000 is exactly the same as 0x0000000. Also equivalent: 0x0, 0, (24/6-9+5). For #1, you can call getPixel on a non-transparent BitmapData, it just doesn't give you the alpha data.

Comment: For #2, you can pass mcMyClip.transform.matrix for the matrix parameter in the BitmapData.draw() call.

Comment: For #3, try if (i%16==0 && i%16==0) { trace(...); } // traces only every 256th pixel

Comment: @aaaidan: I found out some time ago: The MovieClip I work with only has Alpha data  (no colors, everything is 0,0,0, difference only in the alpha value) !

Answer (score 1):

Does the getPixel call work and not the getPixel32? What's the sandbox situation like? Do you have enough "permission" to access the bitmap as data? Perhaps you need a LoaderContext to pass to the Loader that is loading the image? Have you traced/debugged out the Bitmap Data size to see how big it actually is?

Answer (score 0):

No idea if it's as simple as this, but have you tried with `bmdp.width - 1` in the for loop condition?

Answer (score -1):

The constructor for BitMapData takes as its 4th arg an ARGB color value (e.g., 0x00000000 -- eight digits), not an RGB value (e.g., 0x000000 -- six digits). Maybe that's your problem: you haven't supplied the Alpha channel value.

Comment: Appending 0s to 0x0 doesn't change its value; it will still be 0.